# Getting an error when trying to remove a cart item from the WooCommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce, product, cart

On the checkout page I've a button to selected the shipping method. When my cart contains a product which in in a category, I want remove all products from the cart which are in the same category.

```
<button onclick="clear_product_cart()">Check possibility</button>
```

My script :

```
function clear_product_cart(){

  jQuery.post(
      ajaxurl,
      {
          'action': 'clear_cart'              

      },
      function(response){
          alert( ' product removed!');
      });
}
```

In my function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_clear_cart', 'clear_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_cart', 'clear_cart' );
function clear_cart(){
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

       if ( !has_term( 'my_cat', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
       }
    }
die();
}
```

I don't no why, but i have an error 500 after the first product was removed.
Have you a suggestion? thank's

Comment: Solved. My error are simple i have add " session_start " in my custom shipping methode. The error 500 are show because the session are previously declared.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JavaScript` function could be the problem. Please remove it and put this into your `functions.php` file of your child theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'head_data' );
function head_data() { ?>

    <script>
        function clear_product_cart() {

            let a = {action: "clear_cart"};

            jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>", a, function () {
            }).success(function () {
                alert('Product removed!');
            }).fail(function () {
                alert('Error!');
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php }
```

Try it again and tell me if it works. I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: Hi Mr Jo,I have change the script and i have the same error 500. The problem is in the foreach . explication : when i click in the button the function clear_cart are executed. but just the first product are remove not all product in "my_cat". The error 500 appear after the first iteration of foreach

Comment: Hey, you don't have any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you enabled debug logs in WordPress? If yes, it would be helpful to see the error from the log. Maybe you can paste it. 500 can means everything..

Comment: Hummm  debug active right now and hoooooo ... I have creat 3 custom shipping methode and i think it's my shiiping  the problem. [19-Mar-2019 13:20:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/dev/wp-content/themes/my_theme/inc/livraison/my_shipping.php on line 179

Comment: This is not the 500 error. There must be an error in your log which returns 500 to your ajax call.

Comment: My prblem is solved !!! i have just remove  " session_start " I don't know why i have write this .... Pff i'm confius. THNAK'S JO for your help ;)

Comment: Okay. Nice to hear that. But I would recommend my code for the JS function. You can replace the "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>" with the variable ajaxurl again put it into your JS file. Because you can test if the request was successful or not. This makes it more clear in the feature :). And it would be cool, if you can post your solution of the error into the question so it helps other users! Thanks for that